# Is it possible to use custom host headers / bindings with IIS7 Express?

Tags: .net, iis-express, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to configure a new **ASP.NET MVC3** using **IIS7 express** (on my local development machine) to use a **custom domain name**.

eg.

1. my local dev machine.
2. kick open my web browser
3. goto http://dev.www.mydomain.com
4. my visual studio mvc project kicks in

I've hacked my hosts file to include (yes, i saved the file .. which also meant i had to have admin rights enabled ...

```
127.0.0.1 dev.www.mydomain.com
```

I just can't figure out how to use IIS7 express to get configured to do this.

I went to `MVC Project => Properties => Web` and did the following :-
[image]

Then tried to run the site...
[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Stop currently running site if it is running
2. Open `%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config`
   for VS2015+ :`$(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config`
3. Locate the site you are interested in and it would have a binding like

   `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:<your-port-number>:localhost" />`
4. Now add a similar entry `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:<your-port>:dev.www.mydomain.com" />` just below the above bindig entry.
5. run the site again

NOTE: You must start visual studio as administrator because non-localhost binding requires administrator privileges

---

#### Update By Pure Krome:

Further to this, we need to do the following. These comments are in the top of my web.config (along with a few other stuff...).

```
1) netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost.www.foo.com:80/ user=everyone
   netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost.foo.com:80/ user=everyone
   netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost.foobar.com.au:80/ user=everyone
   netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost.pewpew.com:80/ user=everyone
   ... etc ... 
   NOTE: to remove a urlacl: netsh http delete urlacl url=<url in here> .. eg http://foo.com:80

2) ... and we need to edit the main IIS7 express config file to define the url's which will be accepted, per web -site-
    File: C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1200:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:localhost.www.foo.com" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:localhost.foo.com" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:localhost.foobar.com.au" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:localhost.pewpew.com" />
</bindings>
```

Comment: @user578913 - frak me .. are you serious????? I have to now get every member in my team to *manually* edit their apphost.config file ?? WTF! :(

Comment: I am afraid you have to do that @pure ... but I sure hope they will fix this. You could also create a small power shell script for it.

Comment: @Syska - yep, i've forgotton about this question. I've been using this technique since i got this answer. It works wonderfully! I've just got a comment at the top of our web.config with commands (ps command line) how to do this. In fact, i'll update this answer.

Comment: YOWZA WOWZA This is helpful. YOWZA WOWZA

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully been able to accomplish debugging an IIS7-bound site similar to the above.  The only step it appears you are missing is within your project:

1. Select Project => [Project] Properties from the menu
2. Click the "Web" section
3. Select the "Use **Custom** Web Server" option, and set Server Url to "http://dev.www.my-domain.com"

Comment: Question is about IIS Express. :)