# configure hostname for wordpress site using webmatrix

Tags: wordpress, webmatrix, iis-express

How can I configure a wordpress site built using webmatrix on windows to run on a specific hostname instead of localhost with a port number.

For example my site is currently running on http://localhost:64044/
I need to be able to view it via http://www.mydomain.co.uk

I know I can edit my hosts file in windows to point my domain to my local pc like so:
127.0.0.1   www.mydomain.co.uk

but I cant see how or where to configure hostname bindings for the wordpress site in webmatrix?

Answer (score 1):

probably you can't do it directly from WebMatrix. But you can do it manually by editing IIS Express configuration file %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config (WebMatrix uses IIS Express web server). Take a look at following posts

[Binding IIS Express to an IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866547/binding-iis-express-to-an-ip-address/4869367#4869367)

[Is it possible to use custom host headers / bindings with IIS7 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338184/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-host-headers-bindings-with-iis7-express/5341121#5341121)